# how to create book app in android?

Tags: android, html, webview

I am writing an learning app that consists of many pages included text and pictures as well and some highlighted code (say C++) for learning.
I decided to implement this by html WebView but there is some disadvantages:

1.Sometimes webview gets blank (i don't know why!!) and this makes bad user experience

2.Rendering time for webview is very slow as opposed to native widgets like textview & imageview etc. and some times it takes 1 second to load the contents.

and some advantages as well :

1.Styling is very easy in html using css specially for code highlighting in my case

approach:I saved them in my asset folder and load them with loadurl() method up to webview.

Is there a better way to create book-like app in android ? 
How can I reach better performance ? In addition consider styling matters.

Comment: Don't use WebView?

Comment: maybe look into React Native since it all javascript. might be easier with the animations.

Comment: what do you mean ? :) @MuratK.

Comment: oh a long way ... @Droidev

Comment: pretty sure he is saying not to use a webview. you wont be happy with the outcome. look into native code. if you know HTML/JS/CSS, I would look into React Native.

Comment: Maybe use a library like this one: https://github.com/PDDStudio/highlightjs-android

Comment: Thanks but i don't know anything about JS, you meant i have to use native textview and imageview etc ?  @Droidev

Comment: i think thats the point @ShahinSoft. Learn. If you want want done right, do it right. you said it yourself, "makes bad user experience". Don't use a webview. learn react native. Its actually pretty easy. i do my code in AS, and i sat down and created a simple splash screen in react native with an image, textviews, etc. do it right the first time.

Comment: thank you @Droidev i got the best advices :)